# How to use input from dynamic generated textboxes in windows forms?

Tags: windows-forms-designer

I am working on a windows forms project. Theres a button which generates new textboxes.

```
        TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();

        this.positionY += 40;
        txtbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.positionX, this.positionY);
        this.Controls.Add(txtbox);
```

How can I get the input from these generated textboxes?

Can someone help me?

Best regards

JuRi-2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create an array of text boxes and then access them as array items.
I hope the following code helps.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int positionX = 10;
        int positionY = 0;

        TextBox[] txtboxes = new TextBox[3];
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < txtboxes.Length; i++)
            {
                this.positionY += 40;
                txtboxes[i] = new TextBox();
                txtboxes[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.positionX, this.positionY);
                this.Controls.Add(txtboxes[i]);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = "";
            for(int i=0; i<txtboxes.Length;i++)
                str += txtboxes[i].Text + "\n";
            MessageBox.Show(str);
        }
    }
}
```